# Dual monitor resolutions won't stick after boot unknown

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, resolution, xrandr

I had a brownout last night, which forced my CPU to reboot. When it came back up, my dual monitors had the incorrect resolution. Now I have to set them manually after startup.

My main monitor is an Asus and is recognized as Ancor Communications Inc. 24''. My secondary monitor is a ViewSonic and is recognized as Unknown. I checked my `~/.config/monitors.xml` file and get the follow:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="VGA-0">
          <vendor>VSC</vendor>
          <product>0x3919</product>
          <serial>0x01010101</serial>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>1024</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>1920</x>
          <y>56</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-0">
      </output>
      <output name="DVI-0">
          <vendor>ACI</vendor>
          <product>0x2494</product>
          <serial>0x01010101</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="VGA-0">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>1024</height>
          <rate>75</rate>
          <x>1920</x>
          <y>27</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-0">
      </output>
      <output name="DVI-0">
          <vendor>ACI</vendor>
          <product>0x2494</product>
          <serial>0x01010101</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

I noticed the `<vendor>???</vendor>` and duplicate section so removed both, leaving the first `<configuration>...</configuration>`. That didn't help.

Lastly, I need to run `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024` before I can set my secondard montior to the correct resolution.

**CPU information**

```
OS: ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 440 Processor × 3
video card is: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV730
OS type: 64-bit
```

Any ideas what's going on?

**I added the same monitors.xml (without duplicates) to my `/etc/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr/` directory but haven't restarted. I will edit this post after.

**EDIT**

So adding /etc/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr/monitors.xml`with the above information yielded an error saying it could not apply those settings. I noticed the`monitors.xml`file in was edited with the duplicate``tags and with`???` as I described above.

I did run `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024` as usual and both monitors were corrected afterwards. Usually I have to manually set the correct resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out my problem and figured I'd post what I did in case anyone else runs into something similar.

In the end, I edited my `xorg.config` file, added a `.xprofile` file and deleted my `.config/monitors.xml` file.

```
xorg.config

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option          "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option          "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option          "DPMS" "true"
        Option          "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
        Option          "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "VGA0"
        Option          "RightOf" "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option          "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport  0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Option      "Monitor-DVI-0" "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "Monitor-VGA-0" "VGA0"
EndSection
```

---

```
.xprofile

xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024
```

---

A new monitors.xml file was auto-generated on startup and still contains the ??? for the unknown monitor (VGA-0) but it does not contain the duplicates anymore.

Everything seems fine now